# What's the strategy for deciding which feature level is excluded from one hot encoding of a categorical variable?

Tags: predictive-modeling, regression, feature-selection

I'm working on a regression problem with a continuous dependent variable (sale price of a home). Amongst my features are several categorical features, which I'm transforming to "one hot encoded" dummy variables via `Pandas` [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) function.

My question is, in order to avoid the trap of multi-colinearity, one level from each categorical variable must be excluded from the model.`Pandas` provides this with the `drop_first` argument within the `get_dummies` function in which I can optionally exclude the first level from being included in the one hot encoding. However, this strikes me as somewhat arbitrary. Is there a strategy to ensure that the excluded level doesn't affect the accuracy of my regression model? How does one decide which level to exclude?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/8165/127417